# Keeping paragraphs when reading a .txt file

Tags: python, string, io

I have the following problem.
I have a function that reads a .txt file and converts it to a string. However, in doing so I lose all the paragraphs of the file.
For example if my .txt file contains the following:

---

```
Hello everyone I have a problem with reading a file and turning it into a string.

This is a new paragraph, however it is lost once converted to a string.

And this is another paragraph as well.
```

---

And now after reading this .txt file I get back the following string:

---

```
Hello everyone I have a problem with reading a file and turning it into a string.This is a new paragraph, however it is lost once converted to a string.And this is another paragraph as well.
```

---

meaning that all the paragraphs have disappeared.

Now my command for reading this file is:

```
data = iom.read_file_contents(sys.argv[1])
```

and the read_file_contents is a function in the following module named iom:

```
import io


def read_file_contents(name):             

    return open(name).read()


def write_file_contents(name, text):
    with io.open(name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:  #creates .txt file

                outfile.write(unicode(text))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
After request, my full code works as following:

```
data = iom.read_file_contents(sys.argv[1])


for i in data:
    if i not in string.ascii_letters and i not in n and i not in string.punctuation and i !=' ': #removes all non ascii, numbers, punctuation and ' ' characters
        data = data.replace(i,"")


iom.write_file_contents(sys.argv[1],data)  #rewrites the input .txt file by erasing all non ascii, numbers, punctuation and ' ' characters
output = sub.substitute(data, rotation)
iom.write_file_contents(sys.argv[2], output)
```

Meaning that I read a file, I rewrite it by erasing all "weird" characters like φ, then call the substitute function with input a string and a dictionary that maps letters to other letters (enciphers the input):

```
def substitute(str, cipher):      #substitution cipher, takes a string (which will be substituted) and a dictionary


    result = ""
    n = '0123456789'
    for c in str:
        if c in string.uppercase or c in string.lowercase:
            result = result + cipher[c]
        elif c==' ' or c in n or c in string.punctuation:
            result = result + c

    return result
```

and then write the output of the substitute function to a new .txt file.

Comment: What other operations are you doing on `data` before you print it or write it to a file? I bet the problem is occurring there. Please provide a full code sample that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I can't observe that behavior. Could you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? BTW, `open(name).read()` is probably an anti-pattern as it relies on the GC the "close" the file: works only in ref-counting implementation like CPython. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: Looks like you're `.strip()`ping lines somewhere in code you don't show us.

Answer (score 0):

This replaces the newline character, too, which you 'sort of' need to make a paragraph.

```
for i in data:
    if i not in string.ascii_letters and i not in n and i not in string.punctuation and i !=' ': #removes all non ascii, numbers, punctuation and ' ' characters
        data = data.replace(i,"")
```

Though ugly, this should avoid stripping the newline. Håken's answer is better as it simplifies the search for 'bad' characters.

```
for i in data:
    if i not in string.ascii_letters and i not in n and i not in string.punctuation and i !=' ' and i not in '\n': #removes all non ascii, numbers, punctuation and ' ' characters
        data = data.replace(i,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

> I rewrite it by erasing all "weird" characters like φ,

You are also erasing all whitespace except `" "`

How about this instead?

```
letters = string.letters
non_letters = string.punctuation + string.digits + string.whitespace

for c in input_string:
    if c in letters:
        result += cipher[c]
    elif c in non_letters:
        result += c
```

If you only want to keep some whitespace you can choose which ones.

```
non_letters = string.punctuation + string.digits + ' ' + '\n'
```